# How to handle the space in the log

Tags: perl

I am trying to write  a script which will take PID and CPU value but i facing problem with sapce.

Below is the logs which i am  handling :

```
 5899  0   0% D     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/u:4
 6213  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     migration/1
 6214  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/1:0
 6215  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ksoftirqd/1
 6824  1   0% S     1    848K    448K     root     /system/bin/
 6837  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     migration/2
 6838  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/2:0
 6839  2   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ksoftirqd/2
 6840  3   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     migration/3
 6841  3   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/3:0
 6842  3   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ksoftirqd/3
10659  2   0% S    15 297136K  22572K  bg u0_a15   android.proc
10882  0   0% S    13 294316K  22636K  bg u0_a23   com.google.a
12473  1   0% S    13 287420K  19936K  bg u0_a0    com.android.
12612  0   0% S     5   4504K    240K     root     /sbin/adbd
12614  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     k_rmnet_work
13429  0   0% S    28 307800K  22312K  bg u0_a19   com.google.a
13501  0   0% S    11 282628K  19212K  bg u0_a55   com.qrd.simc
13867  3   0% S    16 297644K  27700K  bg u0_a37   com.android.
13927  0   0% S    10 281604K  19552K  fg u0_a38   com.android.
14057  0   0% S    10 283148K  19224K  bg u0_a72   com.asiainfo
14983  2   0% S    14 291744K  21596K  bg u0_a92   com.baidu.Ba
15647  2   0% S    14 293192K  27800K  bg u0_a21   com.android.
20206  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/u:3
32229  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kworker/0:1
   81  1   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     dalrpc_rcv_D
    2  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     kthreadd
    3  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     ksoftirqd/0
    6  0   0% S     1      0K      0K     root     migration/0
```

In the above log i  am trying to catch first column and third column value.

Here is my code:

**$outval_1 is scalar variable i am taking each line with the help of some command.**

```
   my @text_words_1 = split(/\s+/, $outval_1);
    #print "@text_words_1"

    foreach my $val(@text_words_1)
    {
      if($val =~/^\s+/)
      {
        print "Sapce is there\n";
      }
      else
      {
        print "$val\n";
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your lines begin with spaces, so before split you could remove them,

```
$outval_1 =~ s/^ \s+ //x;
```

so that `$text_words_1[0]` is always value from first column.

Comment: Thanks mpapec for quick help. !!

Comment: i just forgot to ask you  about "X" which you have used in the regx. What is the use of the "X"

Comment: `/x` ignores white spaces for better readability, ie. it's same as `s/^\s+//;`

Comment: @mpapec: That is an abuse of the `/x` modifier IMO. `s/^\s+//` is hardly obscure.